# how to configure serde with different value data formats?

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, hive-serde

I have the following code:

```java
private Properties getStreamProperties(String suffix) {
        Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, groupId + "-" + suffix);
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, applicationId + "-" + suffix);
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        streamsConfiguration.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
        // Specify default (de)serializers for record keys and for record values.
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName();
        streamsConfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);
}
```

But my values consist of type string, double and long - not just string. How can I configure the properties to read for all types? Currently, in the messages being produced I can see all the values pushed together as one string value rather than each having their own field.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to look at your **producer** code to see what formats are really sent. `StringSerializer` will always `toString` the data sent, and you can expect `Serdes.String()` to do something similar (if it consumes data from `IntSerializer`, then they will be strings instead)

If you really want to mix types, use JSON/Avro/Protobuf serializers/deserializers in all components in your codes